# Fetch a list of blocked hosts from MySQL server

Tags: mysql, nagios

We have 10 or so web servers that share a few MySQL servers. Due to some networking problems, there were too many connection errors and one of the webservers was blocked. I resolved this by flushing the hosts but it took a short while to notice this.

I want to setup a Nagios/Icinga check to fetch a list of blocked hosts - but I can't see how I could do this as MySQL seems to have no option for it (and there's no host_cache table to check from). I could just add a check for every webserver to try and connect, but I'd rather the check be centralised if possible - if not then I'll have to do it that way.

Comment: `mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -e 'SELECT * FROM blocked_list;'` do you mean something like this?

Comment: Something similar to what that would produce, yes, but obviously that table doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

There is a [host_cache table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-host-cache-table.html). It's in the performance_schema DB.

That will give you a count on connection errors per host, which you can then set up your Nagios alert for.

Comment: This table only introduced in ver. 5.6, do you have any idea how to check this table in prior versions, although it's a memory table in prior versions. Thank.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all blocked hosts by running this sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `host_cache` where SUM_CONNECT_ERRORS > 0
```

The documentation for the host_cache table can be found at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-host-cache-table.html

You can flush the cache executing

```
mysqladmin flush-hosts
```

at the console of the server (maybe you have to add credentials!). The documentation can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/host-cache.html#host-cache-flushing